# e.preventDefault() in Javascript prototype module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, prototype

I am trying to add e.preventDefault(); when **a** tag is clicked. Below is my code but it does not work. Could somebody give me an advice please? Thank you.

```
(function($){
    'use strict';
    var ItemPhoto = function(){
        this.$el = undefined;
        this.getElements();
        this.events();
    }
    ItemPhoto.prototype = {
        getElements: function(){
            this.$el = $('#contaner').find('.image');
            this.$item = $('#contaner').find('.item').find('a');
        },
        events: function(){
            this.$item.on('click', {_self:this}, this.swapImage());
        },
        swapImage: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var _self = e.data._self;
            _self.$el.attr('src', _self.$item.attr('href'));
        }
    }
    var itemPhoto = new ItemPhoto();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're calling `swapImage` rather than binding it to the event handler, thanks to the `()`.

Comment: Ok, I edited the line you mentioned but it still does not work.

Comment: [Your edit solved the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/rx96ma6d/). So I'm rollbacking and closing as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you Oriol for rollbacking the question. Sorry for my less understanding the rule here. I appreciate it that you checked my question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your code is working fine. Check, that jquery is loaded and your function waits till DOM loaded.

Comment: I you can't reproduce the problem described in a question you should vote (or flag if you don't have enough reputation) to close it. Don't post an answer with a random guess.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it about jQuery and DOM loading.